findById(Long id) no funciona? en Spring con DTO
Tengo la siguiente entidad de Sprig, con su repositorio, servicio, DTO y controlador.
Cuando estoy en el incisoController y llamo a la funcion incisoSerice.findById(id) funciona correctamente, al igual que estando en articuloController y llamando a articuloSerice.findById(id).
El problema esta cuando llamo a articuloSerice.findById(id) pasando como parametro un id de un articulo existente desde incisoController, en ese caso no me trae nada.
La clase Inciso es la siguiente:
@Entity
@Table(name = "incisos")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false) // no modifica los metodos Equals y Hash de la supereclase, pero si los utiliza
public class Inciso extends Ley {

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_inciso_padre")
        @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler", "numero", "denominacion", "detalle", "estado",
                        "fechaAlta", "fechaBaja", "fechaModificacion", "motivoModificacion", "activo",
                        "novedadesPersonales",
                        "tipoLey", "articuloPadre", "incisoPadre", "incisos", "subIncisos", "subArticulos" })
        private Inciso incisoPadre;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "incisoPadre", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler", "numero", "denominacion", "detalle", "estado",
                        "fechaAlta", "fechaBaja", "fechaModificacion", "motivoModificacion", "activo",
                        "novedadesPersonales",
                        "tipoLey", "articuloPadre", "incisoPadre", "incisos", "subIncisos", "subArticulos" })
        private List<Inciso> subIncisos = new ArrayList<>();

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_articulo")
        @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler", "numero", "denominacion", "detalle", "estado",
                        "fechaAlta", "fechaBaja", "fechaModificacion", "motivoModificacion", "activo",
                        "novedadesPersonales",
                        "tipoLey", "articuloPadre", "incisoPadre", "incisos", "subIncisos", "subArticulos" })
        private Articulo articulo;
}


el controlador correspondiente a Inciso es el siguiente (omitiendo codigo innecesario):

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/inciso")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class IncisoController {
    @Autowired
    IncisoService incisoService;
    @Autowired
    ArticuloService articuloService;
    @Autowired
    LeyController leyController;
    @Autowired
    NovedadPersonalService novedadPersonalService;

    @GetMapping("/detail/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Inciso>> getById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        if (!incisoService.activo(id))
            return new ResponseEntity(new Mensaje("Inciso no encontrado"), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        Inciso inciso = incisoService.findById(id);
        return new ResponseEntity(inciso, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

private Inciso createUpdate(Inciso inciso, IncisoDto incisoDto) {

        Ley ley = leyController.createUpdate(inciso, incisoDto);
        inciso = (Inciso) ley;

        if (inciso.getArticulo() != null && (inciso.getArticulo().getId() != incisoDto.getIdArticulo())
                && incisoDto.getIdArticulo() != null) {
            inciso.setArticulo(articuloService.findById(incisoDto.getIdArticulo()).get());
        }
    }
 @PostMapping("/create")
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody IncisoDto incisoDto) {
        ResponseEntity<?> respuestaValidaciones = leyController.validationsCreate(incisoDto);

        if (respuestaValidaciones.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
            Inciso inciso = createUpdate(new Inciso(), incisoDto);
            incisoService.save(inciso);
            return new ResponseEntity<Mensaje>(new Mensaje("Inciso creado correctamente"), HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return respuestaValidaciones;
        }
    }

Ademas Inciso tiene una relacion 1:N con él mismo, si desde el controlador de inciso llamo a incisoSerice.findById(idIncisoPadre) con un id existente en la base de datos, tampoco trae el elemento, siendo que idIncisoPadre si deberia traer un elemento de la clase Inciso
